# Why PHP Return JSON With "&quot;"?

Tags: php, json, double-quotes, nusoap

I am working with WSDL for my web services. So, I created a WSDL page and add a function. This function is, connect my table and return JSON value. When I call this function other PHP page, I take successful my values.

```
[{"ID":"1","Number":"1"}]
```

But, when I call this function in my WSDL page, I get it:

```
[{&quot;ID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;Number&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;}]
```

And this my function in WSDL:

```
public function A($a1,$a2,$a3,$o1) 
    {
    include "../conf/database.php";
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM table_users";  
    $SQLResult=mysqli_query($conn,$SQL);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($SQLResult))
    {
        $JSON[] = $row;
    }
    return json_encode($JSON,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_APOS);
    }
```

I found a lot of solutions, but it didn't work. I try **preg_replace, replace** but I can't. How I solve this problem?

My WSDL PHP Page:

```
<?php
require_once "lib/nusoap.php";
$JSON= array();

    public function A($a1,$a2,$a3,$o1) 
    {
    include "../conf/database.php";
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM table_users";  
    $SQLResult=mysqli_query($conn,$SQL);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($SQLResult))
    {
        $JSON[] = $row;
    }
    return json_encode($JSON,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_APOS);
    }

$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("TryFunc", "MyURL");
  $server->wsdl->addComplexType('A',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(
            'a1' => array('name' => 'a1', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
            'a2' => array('name' => 'a2', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
            'a3' => array('name' => 'a3', 'type' => 'xsd:int'),
            'o1' => array('name' => 'o1', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
    )
);
$server->register('A',                   
  array('a1' => 'xsd:string', 'a2' => "xsd:string",'a3' => "xsd:int",'o1' => "xsd:string"),      
   array("return" => "xsd:string"),
    "",
    "",
    "rcp",
    "encoded",
    "document");

@$server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Comment: @KrisRoofe, I remove it but i still take same problem.

Comment: what do you mean `", i get"` : where, how are you visualizing it , how is this function called, in what context ????

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, I test in SoapUI. When I request, I take this.

Comment: and did you echo/log/vardumped the json in php , just to eliminate that what you see isnt what you got ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, When I use echo in my php page, I can successful take JSON. But, I return in WSDL php page, I can't.

Comment: show your code. MCVE please

Comment: @AlpYuktug  `But, when I call this function in my WSDL page`-> show us the code

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I add myWSDL page.

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie, You can see function name is A.

Comment: @AlpYuktug  replace your part of code with this one:- https://3v4l.org/9sPqI

Answer (score -1):

Dead simple: JSON isn't allowed to use single quotes.

It's actually counter-intuitive at least if you use PHP as double quotes will output a variable and single quotes will output the literal variable name itself. Why JSON strictly prefers double quotes is not something I personally know though I do personally consider it a flaw. I was not able to find out *why* in searches on Duck Duck Go and Google. You could research the original author Douglas Crockford and see what programming language(s) he programmed as it may be the reverse of PHP, an oversight, zealous belief, etc.